# How to create wicket custom CssResourceReference which would reference static folder (using spring boot jar packaging)

Tags: java, spring-boot, wicket

I'm trying to use

MarcGiffing/wicket-spring-boot project to get wicket executable jar with resources, however
putting resources (js, css) to /resources (maven folder does not work) and putting resources in
webapp folder also does not work when I try to use CssResourceReference:

```
public static final CssResourceReference jqueryUiLayoutDefaultCss =
        new CssResourceReference(WicketApplication.class,
                "/layout-default.min.css");

public static final CssResourceReference formDefaultCss =
        new CssResourceReference(WicketApplication.class,
                "/default-form.min.css");
```

My question is where to put static files so that they would be accessible when executable spring boot jar is running and static files are are accessed like this

```
    response.render(CssHeaderItem.forReference(new 
    CssResourceReference(WicketApplication.class,"/default-form.min.css")));
```

However, when I put static css and js files in static folder (resources/static) I can access the
static resource via url (i.e localhost:8080/default-form.min.css)

I, also can access static resource like this

```
response.render(CssHeaderItem.forUrl("/default-form.min.css"));
```

so, how to access static resources via reference (using CssResourceReference and not url)?

Answer (score 0):

ok,

so the basic idea is to do like this

```
public static final CssResourceReference formDefaultCss =
        new CssResourceReference(WicketApplication.class,
                "/default-form.min.css");
```

and then in a web page class `(public class myWebPage extends WebPage)` method
`public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response)` use the same base class (in this case it is `WicketApplication.class`), i.e

```
 response.render(CssHeaderItem.forReference(new 
    CssResourceReference(WicketApplication.class,"/default-form.min.css")));
```

bear in mind that WicketApplication.class in this case is not a WicketApplication (i.e `public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication`), but

```
SpringBootApplication.class
```

i.e

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WicketApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(WicketApplication.class);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

also, be aware of these locations for static content while using spring boot (excerpt from )

> Spring Boot comes with a pre-configured implementation of
> ResourceHttpRequestHandler to facilitate serving static resources.
>
> By default, this handler serves static content from any of /static,
> /public, /resources, and /META-INF/resources directories that are on
> the classpath. Since src/main/resources is typically on the classpath
> by default, we can place any of these directories there.
>
> For example, if we put an about.html file inside the /static directory
> in our classpath, then we can access that file via
> http://localhost:8080/about.html. Similarly, we can achieve the same
> result by adding that file in other mentioned directories.